# Code Structure for Very Simple c++ Text Adventure

Tags: c++, structure

I'm trying to write a simple text adventure game in c++ but as its now getting longer I am looking for advice on how to structure my code better.

The game is very simple, its really more of a chance for me to play with c++ as I am relatively new to it. I print a block of text to the terminal, ask the player a questions, then the process repeats itself with a new question. Each "node" of the code looks like this:

```
string agreechoice1;
void Choice1()
{
     cout << "some text describing situation, then the question. 
                           Usually a choice between A or B \n\n";
     while (!(agreechoice1 == "A" || agreechoice1 == "B"))
     {
          cin >> agreechoice1;
          if (agreechoice1 == "A")
          {
              Choice2();
              return;
          }
          if (agreechoice1 == "B")
          {
              Choice3();
              return;
          }
          cout << "if they havent chosen A or B this will tell 
           them that, and they will have another chance to try. \n\n";
      }
      return;
}
```

So, choosing A will send them to Choice2(), which will do the same thing as here.

My question is how should i structure this? What is good c++ practise? I'm now in a situation where i have 14 "choices", so i have blocks of this code 14 times. Would it be better to have each of these in a separate file, then link them all together by creating a mainfile? Or is there another, better way to structure it that I've not thought of?

As a secondary question, is this block of code "efficient" - ie, is there a better way to carry out what I am trying to do here?

Thank you!
(ps, this is my first time posting a question here, so apologies if I've broken any rules or anything!)

Comment: Questions about working code are best asked on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) Stackexchange site.

Comment: thank you! ill add it there instead

Comment: If you input as a character, you could use a `switch`.

Comment: You may want to consider placing the answers and other attributes (such as function pointers) into a table.  You could search the table for the input, then execute the associated function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this problem, every time you have to consider the simplicity over architecture.

This problem could be described as a graph with nodes. See [Node graph architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_graph_architecture#:%7E:text=Node%20graph%20architecture%20is%20a,visualization%20of%20the%20node%20graph.) . Every situation (question) could be a node, and they could be connected to several other nodes. I suggest to use a c++ library instead of implementing your own graph functionality. Like [Boost's graph library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/)

One of the most simple solutions is what you started. Separate functions for each situation. Leading to a new function over and over. However, it is simple and fast to implement, harder to modify, and has a lot of repeated code. For example, the answering part.

As mentioned in the comments, you could use a switch statement inside the while to simplify the architecture a bit. It has a great advantage to easy to add new answers.

```cpp
cin >> agreechoice1
switch (agreechoice1)
case "A" :
    Choice2();
    break;
case "B" :
    Choice3();
    break;
// New answer as seen above
case "Z" :
    Choice42();
    break;
```

If you move to the [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) you can use [classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/).
I would create a class called choice, with a constructor describe the situation, the possible answers, and the next choices. Something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Question {
    std::string questionText;
    std::map<std::string, Question*> answersAndNextQuestions;
public:
    Question(const std::string& textToAsk) {
        questionText = textToAsk;
    }
    void AddAnswer(std::string answerText, Question* nextQuestion) {
        answersAndNextQuestions[answerText] = nextQuestion;
    }
    void Ask() {
        std::cout << questionText << std::endl;
        std::string answer;
        std::cin >> answer;
        // should handle invalid answers
        answersAndNextQuestions[answer]->Ask();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Question first("Is this the first?");
    Question second("Is this the second?");
    Question third("Is this the third?");

    first.AddAnswer("Yes", &second);
    first.AddAnswer("No", &third);

    first.Ask();
}
```